# Joining two mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I m creating a search using php , there i need to search companies from **company name** and **company category** .

*company_content tb*

title
categories _id

*company_category tb*

title  (category name)
id
parent_id (categories id on on content table)

here's my query

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT  b.title FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a, sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id=81 UNION
SELECT  a.title  FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a, sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE a.categories_id=b.id  AND  a.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id=81");
```

is this type of union valid ? please advice

**UPDATE 01**

```
   $query=mysql_query("SELECT  b.title
FROM sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id = 81
UNION
SELECT  a.title
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a join
      sltdb_cddir_categories b
      on a.categories_id = b.id
WHERE a.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id = 81");
$json=array();
while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[]=array(
        'value'=> $display["title"],
        'label'=>$display["title"]
    );
}




echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Side note: The mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should look into [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) and prepared statements.  Also, watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Matthew Johnson : can you advice me on this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440392/ajax-search-when-click-on-category-name-show-the-items-under-that-category-as-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT  b.title
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a, sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id=81
UNION
SELECT  a.title
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a, sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE a.categories_id=b.id  AND  a.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id=81;
```

In the first subquery, the join to `a` is unimportant.  The values are never used.  This seems to be an equivalent query:

```
SELECT  b.title
FROM sltdb_cddir_categories b
WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id = 81
UNION
SELECT  a.title
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a join
      sltdb_cddir_categories b
      on a.categories_id = b.id
WHERE a.title like '%".$searchg."%' AND b.parent_id = 81;
```

If the purpose is to get all titles from the two tables where the corresponding `parent_id` is 81 and the title matches the pattern, then this query looks reasonable.

Comment: :in my case b.title is category title where i want to display content which related to that specific category and 
a.title is content title(content which coming under that category)
    
    currently individual content searching is work where as if i try to search something from category  name only category name
autofiltering but reuslts not showing when search button click. please advice

Comment: kindly please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440392/ajax-search-when-click-on-category-name-show-the-items-under-that-category-as-re

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a `LEFT JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.title, b.title 
FROM  sltdb_cddir_content a 
LEFT JOIN sltdb_cddir_categories b
ON a.categories_id=b.id
WHERE  (b.title like '%".$searchg."%' OR a.title like '%".$searchg."%')
AND b.parent_id = 81
```

Comment: :in my case b.title is category title where i want to display content which related to that specific category and a.title is content title(content which coming under that category) currently individual content searching is work where as if i try to search something from category name only category name autofiltering but reuslts not showing when search button click . please advice. i have update my question see UPDATE o1

Comment: kindly please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440392/ajax-search-when-click-on-category-name-show-the-items-under-that-category-as-re